# How to get count and value using one t-sql statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here is what i am trying to get:-

```
SELECT 
  Column1, 
  Count(Column1), 
  Count(Column2)
FROM Table1
```

I know this query is invalid. But is there any way I can all the values of Column1 and Count of Column1 and Count of Column2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OVER clause modifies the aggregate range to allow the query to happen as you want

```
SELECT 
  Column1, 
  Count(Column1) OVER (), 
  Count(Column2) OVER ()
FROM Table1
```

Edit:

above for SQL Server 2005+

Edit 2:

The CROSS JOIN/COUNT solution in SQL Server 2000 is not reliable under load.

Try this from multiple connections, note @@ROWCOUNT never equals T2.cnt in connection 2

```
--connection 1 
set nocount on;
drop table dbo.test_table;
GO
create table dbo.test_table
(
    id_field uniqueidentifier not null default(newid()),
    filler char(2000) not null default('a')
);
GO
create unique clustered index idx_id_fld on dbo.test_table(id_field);
GO
while 1 = 1
insert into dbo.test_table default values;

--connection 2 
select T2.cnt, T1.id_field, T1.filler
from dbo.test_table T1
cross join (select COUNT(*) as cnt from dbo.test_table) T2
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT

select T2.cnt, T1.id_field, T1.filler
from dbo.test_table T1
cross join (select COUNT(*) as cnt from dbo.test_table) T2
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT

select T2.cnt, T1.id_field, T1.filler
from dbo.test_table T1
cross join (select COUNT(*) as cnt from dbo.test_table) T2
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

Edit3: cyberkiwi stated the test is wrong. Rubbish.

If you forget @@ROWCOUNT, you can see `cnt` is different to the row count in SSMS "grid mode"

Now, you use `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` and it does give correct results, but if you are busy enough to get inconsistent results do you really want to run this?

Use a temp table to ensure a consistent dataset if you are running SQL Server 2000.

Comment: @nathan gonzalez: yes, SQL Server 2005 +

Comment: @cyberkiwi: The transaction does not work. Forget @@ROWCOUNT then. Just check rownumber in SSMS "results to grid": you get more rows then COUNT(*) which is first column.

Comment: @cyberkiwi: Do you know what @@ROWCOUNT does: results of last query? cnt would equal @@ROWCOUNT then. Did you read my update, without @@ROWCOUNT?

Comment: @cyberkiwi: thank you: I would have suggested the same as you until this bit me, big time, on a busy server.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT column1,(SELECT COUNT(Column1),COUNT(Column2)) AS CNT FROM Table1
```

That should get you what you want, then when you run your fetch command you use it like you would normally.

E.g. in php, 
`$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query));
 echo $rows['CNT'];`

Comment: This would fail, miserably. The subquery will probably run for each row, you have one alis for 2 columns, it doesn't make sense in SQL Server...

Comment: Works just fine for me on a MySQL 5 server. I just assumed that because SQL is ambiguous of what type of server, it would work.

Answer (score 0):

The question, as asked, does not make sense.  Do you mean that you want the counts of individual combinations of values of Col1 and Col2?  If so:

```
select column1,column2,count(*)
  from table1
 group by column1, column2
```

If this is not what you want please try to give some sample data, what the inputs might look like and what your desired output would be.